# Simplify itemize commands typesetting

Tags: lyx, enumerate, itemize, org-mode

If your document use `itemize` a lot of time, you are likely to get fed up putting `\begin{}...\end{}`. Is there any better way to do this? Something like a org mode of emacs use or lyx use?

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question? In LyX you do not have to write `\begin{}...\end{}`. You just use alt + p, i for itemize or alt + p, e for enumerate. Or alternatively go to the layout menu at the top right (which says "Standard" on a new document) and change it to "itemize" or "enumerate".

Comment: IMHO editor's shortcut is the best way to do this. Also auto completion.

Answer (score 6):

One easy option for simple list is the `wiki` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wiki}
\begin{document}
\wikiEnvironments
# One 
# Two 
This a normal paragraph  
* One 
* Two 
* Three 
Another normal paragraph 
;[One description] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.  
;[Another] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
\nowikiEnvironments
\end{document}
```

But as the Herbert's answer, do not allow nested list. For this is better the package `outlines`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{outlines}
\begin{document}
\begin{outline}[enumerate]
\1 First level
\1 First level again 
\2 Second level 
\3 Third level 
\4 Fourt level 
\0 Normal text
\1 Another list
\end{outline}
\begin{outline}
\1 First level
\1 First level again 
\2 Second level 
\3 Third level 
\4 Fourt level 
\0 Normal text
\1 Another list
\end{outline}
\end{document}
```

Another interesting options could be `iitem` or `easylist` packages.

Answer (score 1):

define shortcuts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\BI\itemize
\let\EI\enditemize
\let\IT\item
\begin{document}

\BI
\IT foo
\IT[+] bar
\IT baz
\EI

\end{document}
```

Comment: wiki package is not available in miktex. Where can I download it from?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to use the outlines package. It is easy to switch itemize, enumerate, types of nested lists.

I found using outlines and some custom code in the sublime editor allows me to have a very flexible way of working with outlines. I can promote, demote, re-order, and ultimately reformat so that the outlines are indented properly.

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/outlines

My latex code looks like:

```
\q{My outline title}{
\1 An Exposure is the basic unit that measures a policy's exposure to loss.
    \2 The exposure serves as the basis for the calculation of premium.
    \2 Base rates are expressed as a rate per exposure. 
    }
```

With a custom environment it reduces the amount of latex code to write.