# auto-starting itemize with \item?

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize

I frequently write slides in beamer, and besides a few macros I use (e.g. for two-column frame), I often type `\begin{itemize}` and `\end{itemize}`. What would be a nice TeXish way for either starting the itemization automatically when `\item` outside of itemization/enumeration is encountered?

Or alternately, how to write a macro which would do something like (pseudocode, this does not work unfortunately as it is):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etextools}
\def\firstitem{\begin{itemize}\AfterGroup{\end{itemize}}\item}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{title}
        \firstitem a
        \item b
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But how would you know when the `itemize` is complete?  By giving an unbalanced `\end` without the corresponding `\begin`?  Ugh.

Comment: As Steven says, you have to tell LaTeX when the `itemize` ends; so why obfuscating your input?

Comment: If you tire of typing in the `\begin{itemize}`, you could always create a shortcut macro:  `\def\BI{\begin{itemize}}
\def\EI{\end{itemize}}` so that the invocation would be `\BI
\item first
\item second
\EI`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: at the end of the enclosing group (column, block, frame) -- that's why I thought of using `\AfterGroup`.

Comment: Would that work if you wanted to continue with non-itemized content within the same frame?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Of course that would not work, which is just fine for me. I can always begin and end the environment explicitly. And besides that, I only very rarely use non-itemized content in slides.

Comment: This may help... http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150865/simplify-itemize-commands-typesetting